# Execute a command on remote machine using telnet in a single line

Tags: python, command, telnet

I would like to execute a command on a remote machine using telnet as,

telnet x.x.x.x command or similar

I want to include this as part of a script in Python ( subprocess ) and hence need it in one line. Or, are there any other ways to do the same?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this useful? To send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: Yes, you could use both `stdin` and `stdout` to communicate with a Telnet binary.  But why not just use `telnetlib` instead, as I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on `subprocess`, you could try Python's built-in [`telnetlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) instead.

A complete example that does almost exactly what you want is available as an example in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example

I would personally also see if SSH is available on the target system.  Not only will you be using a secure connection, but you can also set up SSH keys and use SSH's built-in support for executing a single command (e.g. `ssh user@example.com ls -l`).

Comment: Are we able to run all types of commands on a remote server using telnetlib that you suggested here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
empty -f -i in -o out telnet foo.bar.com
empty -w -i out -o in "ogin:" "luser\n"
empty -w -i out -o in "assword:" "TopSecret\n"
empty -s -o in "who am i\n"
empty -s -o in "exit\n"
```

http://empty.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283747/15931) solution will be useful, but as stated in there, it won't work in case you need user/password authentication.

In order to skip manual user/password authentication, setting up ssh keys is the way to go. There is a short explanation about this here: [SSH to a server without password for Admin Ease](http://www.web-manual.net/linux-3/ssh-configuration-from-source-to-target-server-for-admin-ease-ssh-key-authentication/)